# how do one gets access to the MySQL-DB created by graphcool cli deploy

Tags: mysql, graphcool

I am quite new to graphcool as a framework and i like that i can run it locally now. **To get access from backend side to the cluster, what do i need to do?**

`gc deploy -dev`

exposes some endpoints on localhost:60000.

and
`lsof -i :60000`
shows two containers. how could i possible access them to manipulate my data stored with gc from a backend point of view.

Please provide me manuals or useful links. i thank you in advance

Comment: graphcool is used whenever you want to build an app serverless, your backend is graphcool. Maybe you are thinking in graphql. In that case your backend must to implement the resolvers

Comment: check https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/deployment/database-access-eif6eing5o